# How to create circle image with user initials centered in the circle

Tags: xamarin.ios

Need to create a circle image that has the user's initials centered within the circle. Similar to how circle icons appear in Gmail.  Any third-party component recommendations would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I [found some Swift code](https://github.com/claudot/Swift-UIImageView-Letters/blob/master/Classes/UIImageView%2BLetters.swift) that does exactly what I need.  Just had to convert it all to C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static NSString ToNSString(this string text)
    {
        return new NSString(text);
    }

    public static void ToCircle(this UIImageView imageView, UIColor color, string text = null, double fontSize = 15.0, NSMutableDictionary<NSString, NSObject> customTextAttributes = null)
    {
        imageView.ToCustomFormat(color, true, text, fontSize, customTextAttributes);
    }

    public static void ToCustomFormat(this UIImageView imageView, UIColor color, bool isCircle, string text = null, double fontSize = 15.0, NSMutableDictionary<NSString, NSObject> customTextAttributes = null)
    {
        var scale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
        var imageSize = imageView.Bounds.Size;

        if (imageView.ContentMode == UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill ||
            imageView.ContentMode == UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill ||
            imageView.ContentMode == UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit ||
            imageView.ContentMode == UIViewContentMode.Redraw)
        {
            imageSize.Width =  (nfloat) Math.Floor((imageSize.Width * scale) / scale);
            imageSize.Height = (nfloat) Math.Floor((imageSize.Height * scale) / scale);
        }

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, scale);
        var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

        if (isCircle)
        {
            var path = CGPath.EllipseFromRect(imageView.Bounds);
            context?.AddPath(path);
            context?.Clip();
        }

        context?.SetFillColor(color.CGColor);
        var rect = new CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.Width, height: imageSize.Height);
        context?.FillRect(rect);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {                
            NSString nsText = text.ToNSString();
            UIStringAttributes textAttributes = customTextAttributes == null
                                                ? getDefaultTextAttributes(fontSize)
                                                : new UIStringAttributes(customTextAttributes);

            CGSize textSize = nsText.GetSizeUsingAttributes(textAttributes);
            var bounds = imageView.Bounds;
            var textRect = new CGRect(x: bounds.Size.Width / 2 - textSize.Width / 2, 
                                      y: bounds.Size.Height / 2 - textSize.Height / 2, 
                                      width: textSize.Width, 
                                      height: textSize.Height);

            nsText.DrawString(textRect, textAttributes);
        }

        var newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        if (newImage != null)
        {
            imageView.Image = newImage;    
        }
    }

    private static UIStringAttributes getDefaultTextAttributes(double fontSize = 15.0)
    {
        var defaultAttrs = new NSMutableDictionary<NSString, NSObject>
                            {
                                {UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Black},
                                {UIStringAttributeKey.Font, UIFont.SystemFontOfSize((nfloat) fontSize)}
                            };

        return new UIStringAttributes(defaultAttrs);
    }
}

// Copyright (c) 2017 Paul-Anatole CLAUDOT - author of Swift code
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, i'm giving u a little, not complete, piece of code.

> UIView yourview = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
>
> yourview.Layer.CornerRadius = 50f;

this will create a view rounded, then u have to add the initials centerd in the box

> UILabel yourlabel = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, (100 - 40) / 2, 100,
> 40));
>
> yourlabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
>
> yourlabel.Text = "PG";

yourview.add(yourlabel);

this should work as u expected.

sorry didn't see u want an image so this is the part to add the image

> var img = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
>
> img.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill;
>
> img.ClipsToBounds = true;
>
> img.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("image");
>
> yourview.Add(img);

you should add the image before then the label